# How to get string value from the for loop in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

```java
def loopCount = No_Of_TEST.toInteger()

for (int i = 1; i <= TEST; i++) {
    def paramInput = input(
        id: "paramInput-${i}",
        message: "Enter TEST${i} Value",
        parameters: [
            string(name: "Control_IP_${i}", defaultValue: '10.0.0.0', description: "Control IP")
                            
        ]
    )
}
```

I have tried with the

```java
sh "echo  ${params.Control_IP_${i}}"
```

tried with also:

```java
env.Control_IP = params["Control_IP_${i}"]

echo "${env.Control_IP}"
```

But getting the "null" after echo.

Answer (score 0):

you reasign `paramInput` variable each time
`params` - stores initial params not dynamic
`env` - only environment variable

you can use hack:

```
int TEST = 3

Map inputParams = [:]
for (int i = 1; i <= TEST; i++) {
    def paramInput = input(
        id: "paramInput-${i}",
        message: "Enter TEST${i} Value",
        parameters: [
            string(name: "Control_IP_${i}", defaultValue: '10.0.0.0', description: "Control IP"),
            // string(name: "Control_IP_${i}2", defaultValue: '10.0.0.0', description: "Control IP")
        ]
    )

    // if several params passed it will be map
    if (paramInput instanceof Map) {
      paramInput.each { name,value ->
        inputParams[name] = value
      }
    // owerwise string 
    } else {
      // if you have only one param you can remove entire if and have only this line
      inputParams["Control_IP_${i}"] = paramInput
    }
}

// to display all 
for (int i = 1; i <= TEST; i++) {
  println(inputParams["Control_IP_${i}"])
}
```

depends on you pipeline inputParams can not be resolved in functions if you have any, so you need to add

```
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field
Map inputParams = [:]
```

if you want to do it global var